# What is a "applicative transformation" in naturality of traversability?

Tags: haskell, applicative, traversable

The `traverse` and `sequenceA` function in `Traversable` class must satisfy the following 'naturality' laws:

```
t . traverse f == traverse (t . f)
t . sequenceA == sequenceA . fmap t
```

for every 'applicative transformation' `t`. But what is it?

It doesn't seem to work for `instance Traversable []` for `t = tail`:

```
Prelude> tail . sequenceA $ [[1],[2,3]]
[[1,3]]
Prelude> sequenceA . fmap tail $ [[1],[2,3]]
[]
```

Nor for `t = join (++)` (repeat the list twice):

```
Prelude Control.Monad> join (++) . sequenceA $ [[1],[2,3]]
[[1,2],[1,3],[1,2],[1,3]]
Prelude Control.Monad> sequenceA . fmap (join (++)) $ [[1],[2,3]]
[[1,2],[1,3],[1,2],[1,3],[1,2],[1,3],[1,2],[1,3]]
```

So for what `t` they are satisfied?

Comment: Another thing to note in the `Data.Traversable` documentation is that "The naturality law is implied by parametricity." This basically means that any definition of `traverse` that passes the type checker will obey the naturality law; you don't have to worry about it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Hackage page for Data.Traversable defines an applicative transformation as follows.

> [A]n applicative transformation is a function
>
> ```
> t :: (Applicative f, Applicative g) => f a -> g a
> ```
>
> preserving the Applicative operations, i.e.
>
> ```
> t (pure x) = pure x
>
> t (x <*> y) = t x <*> t y
> ```

The simplest example of this would be the identity function. `id` is an applicative transformation. A more specific example for lists would be `reverse`.

```
reverse (pure x) = reverse [x] = [x] = pure x
-- (the (<*>) law is more difficult to show)
```

And you can verify in GHCi that the laws you reference do hold for `reverse`.

```
Prelude> reverse . sequenceA $ [[1], [2,3]]
[[1,3],[1,2]]
Prelude> sequenceA . fmap reverse $ [[1], [2,3]]
[[1,3],[1,2]]
```

---

Source: [Data.Traversable](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.10.1.0/docs/Data-Traversable.html)

Comment: The `<*>` law is more difficult to show formally, but if you express it in terms of `concat` and `map`, I think it will become at least intuitively clear. The basic principle is that `concat (reverse (map reverse xss)) = reverse (concat xss)`. Looking at a few small examples should convince anyone that this is true. `reverse (concat [[1,2], [3,4,5]]) = [5,4,3,2,1] = concat [[5,4,3], [2,1]] = concat (reverse (map reverse [[1,2], [3,4,5]]))`, for instance.